# mlDeploy with Gradle fails offline, succeeds online

Tags: gradle, marklogic, marklogic-dhf

We've upgraded our setup to Gradle 6.4, DHF 5.2.0, and MarkLogic 11 from Gradle 5.2.1, DHF 5.2.0, and MarkLogic 10.9.2. The upgrades went smoothly, and `gradlew mlDeploy` runs successfully in online mode. However, it fails in offline mode with the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\Code\DHF-Proj\build.gradle' line: 30

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.marklogic.ml-data-hub', version: '5.8.1'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.marklogic.ml-data-hub:com.marklogic.ml-data-hub.gradle.plugin:5.8.1')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    maven(file:/D:/Code/DHF-Proj/build/offline/maven-repo/)
```

I manually downloaded the DHF-5.8.1 JAR at D:/Code/DHF-Proj/build/offline/maven-repo/, but the error persists. What could be the reason for this issue?

Comment: It's easier to reason about and debug dependency issues if you show your build.gradle, or at least the relevant parts with plugins, dependencies, configuratios, repositories, etc.

Comment: Gradle is telling you that it cannot find the "ml-data-hub" Gradle plugin. You need to ensure that the directory containing dependencies contains the ml-data-hub jar AND all of its dependencies. Simply downloading a single jar will not work, you need all the dependencies as well.